# Help with images and arrays

Tags: php, html

I have an assignment for school call Poker game. I have to deal a random card of five using HTML. I also need to have an array to deal the cards. My main question is can you have images in an array and if so how can it be done? I tried this method:

```
$my_array = array(img src="2Spade.gif", img src="2Club.gif")
```

but this is incorrect! Can anyone give me suggestions on how to build the program provide sample code for me to try?

Comment: Judging from `array(img src="2Spade.gif", img src="2Club.gif")` you have some serious learning to do before starting any development. Don't take this the wrong way but you can't start any programming before you understand the basic syntax and how server-client works.

Comment: please use a code block here.

Comment: You should first read about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and learn the PHP syntax in general.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to have in the array is the string which holds the location of the image, not the image itself.

```
$cardArray = array("2Spade.gif", "2Club.gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly wanted to have the code source in the array you could do this:

```
$my_array = array("img src=\"2Spade.gif\"", "img src=\"2Club.gif\"");
```

Then to use it you'd do something like:

```
if( is_array( $my_array ) && count( $my_array ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $my_array as $card ) {
        echo '<' . $card . ' />';
    }
}
```

But I think Sam Dufel's answer is the better way to create and store the information in an array ...